# Low speed cheap motor

Tags: dc-motor, circuit-design, potentiometer

I am in need of a cheap DC motor that spins at a very low speed, preferably around 10-15rpm. As I am new to electrical engineering, I am not quite sure what to do. The only things I know of are expensive high torque slow motors, which I do not need. The only other idea I had was to make a circuit comprising of only a fast motor, battery, and potentiometer to slow down the motor. Would this work? Would I be able to get a over 1000 rpm motor down to 10rpm? Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This question is not a _"recommendations for specific products"_ question. It is _"how can I make a cheap DC motor go slower"_ question.

Comment: Have you considered a [stepper motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepper_motor)? Or perhaps a [geared motor](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12367)?

Comment: *make a circuit comprising of only a fast motor, battery, and potentiometer to slow down the motor.* That **for certain** will not work, and if you could even make the motor spin slowly, it would take almost nothing to stop it from spinning. An alternative to the stepper motor is to use **gears** to slow the speed down. It has been done that way for centuries so nothing new.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified motor power, nor range of voltage for you motor. I do assume you want to power the motor from battery, so recommended option here can be a 12V DC motor with gearbox. Try to find them on any popular online sites by searching 'DC motor gearbox low rpm'. By quick view there are plenty of options for less than £10. There is a selection of metal or plastic gearbox with compact build.
It will cost more if you are about more powerful motor or higher voltage motor.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use gears. Of course you can make your own gearbox. But if you're the hacker/hobbyist type on tight budget, you can do this with hacked material for between $5 to $20.

Here's a couple of ways:

1) Use a continuous rotation servo

1a) Buy an off-brand but reliable servo, the kind used for RC planes. Plenty on Ebay, Amazon, and online stores. (Sadly, hobby shops have mostly disappeared.)

1b) Google how to modify these servos for continuous rotation. Normally, servos need a pulse signal which determines the servo arm position. The continuous rotation modification allows the output gear to continuously turn.

1c) Disconnect the motor from the electronic circuit board and drive it directly.

So now you have a small DC motor with a gearbox for slow rotation. You can drive it from say 3V to 6V to adjust the speed.

If you need higher torque:

2) Auto window motor

2a) Buy somebody's used car power window motor with gearbox on Ebay or Craigslist

2b) These usually have an output gear so find a matching gear, or make a hole in a plastic wheel and press-fit it onto the output gear (I've done this; can work quite well)

If you need only a tiny bit of torque:

3) Very Slow PWM

Drive the DC motor with a very slow PWM signal with very narrow pulses from a microcontroller. For example, 10 Hz rate with a 10 % duty cycle. Yes, the rotation will be rough, not unlike a stepper motor, but hey you didn't give us any specs to work with.